# How to get rid of these insects from my home

Tags: pest-control

I need urgent help. I woke up this morning to find out that there are about 2 dozen honey bees or wasps flying around in my apartment's gallery. 20 minutes later they settled down like so:

[image: unidentified insects]

One of them got inside and stung me. Please identify what I am dealing with and more importantly, how to get rid of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a swarm of bees. Please don't kill these animals, but call a bee keeper. They will normally take these bees away for free. If you don't know a bee keeper nearby, please try something like the animal ambulance (or animal welfare organization that is active in your region).

For example, here in the Netherlands (where I live), the bee keepers association has a list of bee keepers that you can call. For each region another bee keeper will come and take away the swarms for free. Don't wait too long, after a few days they will settle and it becomes more difficult to take them away.

Comment: It's been exactly 1 year (and 3 days) and same thing happened today. Any idea why they would choose my apartment second time?